# How do I prove that L(2) < 1 and L(3) > 1 given when only given the integral..

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions, definite-integrals, logarithms

We know that $$L(x) = \int_{1}^{x} \frac{dt}{t}, \quad x> 0$$
And we cannot use that $L(x) =\ln(x)$. How do we prove that $L(2) < 1$ and $L(3) > 1$ ?

Comment: Draw appropriate rectangles.

Comment: if $t>1$ then $\dfrac{1}{t}<1$. If for all $x$ in $[a,b]$ $f(x)\leq g(x)$ then $\displaystyle \int_a^b f(x)dx\leq \int_a^b g(x)dx$

Comment: To prove L(3)>1 consider rectangles $(1,0),(1,1/3),(3,0),(3,1/3)$ and $(1,1/3),(1,1/2),(2,1/3),(2,1/2)$

Answer (score 1):

For the first part, $\frac 1t \le 1$ for $1 \le t \le 2$

For the second part, find a number of rectangles with bases between $1$ and $3$ that are all below $\frac 1t$ and area summing to at least $1$